# Fetching Max Date in oracle Query

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Hi Can any body please help me out to solve this issues
I am suppose to fetch the latest stud Next Month according to Course ID
Table Name:Course

```
 Stud Id     Stud Course Id     Stud Curr Month    stud Next Month

1               c001            01-APR-13              01-JUL-13
1               c002            10-APR-13              10-OCT-13
1               c003            10-OCT-12              10-OCT-13
1               c001            01-JUL-13              01-OCT-13
1               c002            10-OCT-13              10-JAN-13
```

I Am in very beginning stage in oracle 9i, so please help me to solve this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
select stud_course_id, max(stud_next_month) 
  from course
  group by stud_course_id;
```

Comment: Hi, This is the results what am expecting, thanks very much for your help

Comment: And you do not mark this as the answer to your question because...?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Stud_Course_ID
  FROM Course
  WHERE Stud_Next_Month = (
    SELECT MAX(Stud_Next_Month)
    FROM Course)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am suppose to fetch the latest stud Next Month according to Course ID, Can you help me for this

Comment: @Sajini - sorry, I don't understand. Based on the data in your question, what do you want the query results to be?

Comment: I need to list out the latest dates for the particular course id, lets see the above table example,  For C001 the latest date is 01-oct-13 and for C002 the latest is 10-jan-13  and for c003 the latest is 10-OCT-13, like this i need, can u help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
  SELECT STUD_COURSE_ID, STUD_CURR_MONTH, STUD_NEXT_MONTH
      FROM (SELECT STUD_COURSE_ID, STUD_CURR_MONTH, STUD_NEXT_MONTH,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STUD_COURSE_ID ORDER BY STUD_NEXT_MONTH DESC) RNUM
               FROM COURSE)
     WHERE RNUM = 1;
```